# Set max length UITextField

Tags: swift, xcode

How to limit the number of characters in a UITextField?
I need to to display max 10 characters

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let textFieldCadena = textField.text, let range = Range(range, in: textFieldCadena) else {
            return false
        }
        let nuevaCadena = textFieldCadena.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        if nuevaCadena.isEmpty {
            textField.text = "0"
            return false
        } else if textField.text == "0" {
            textField.text = string
            return false
        }


        if textField == textField {
            let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789 ")
            let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
            return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
        }


        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As decribed here You can use .maxlength in swift 5 to set character length.  Credit to article here:

https://www.swiftdevcenter.com/max-character-limit-of-uitextfield-and-allowed-characters-swift/

```
self.textField.maxLength = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the check for character count first

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
      guard 
          let textFieldCadena = textField.text, 
          let range = Range(range, in: textFieldCadena),
          textFieldCadena.count <= 10
          else { return false }  
      ...
}
```